# C# Observable collection Group by on nested collection

Tags: c#, collections, observablecollection

Below is my model class

```
public class TechnicianCalendar : INPCBase
{
    #region members

    private int _avgTravelMph; // Average Travel MPH
    private string _startZipCd; // Starting zip code
    private string _workCenterZipCd; // Work center zip code
    private long _defaultWorkAreaId; // Default work area ID`enter code here`
    private long _orgId; // Organization id
    private string _cntrlCtrName; // Control center name
    private long _calendarId; // Calendar ID
    private bool _transmitFlag; // Transmit Flag
    private Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> _techttandKeys;
    private ObservableCollection<TechnicianPendingJobs> pjobs;
    private ObservableCollection<TechnicianDay> days;
    private SortedList<DateTime, TechnicianDay> slDays;
    private ObservableCollection<TechnicianListOfTerritories> technicianTerr;

}
```

Below is my Sub Modal class on which I need to group the data

```
 public class TechnicianListOfTerritories : INPCBase
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _listOfTechTerritoriesandKeys;
        public Dictionary<string, string> ListOfTechTerritoriesandKeys
        {
            get
            {
                return _listOfTechTerritoriesandKeys;
            }
            set
            {
                _listOfTechTerritoriesandKeys = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have Collection of this model class

I need to group the data on ObservableCollection technicianTerr;

I tried the below one but No  again same data is populating

```
    var test = this.Technicians.GroupBy(ter => ter.TechnicianTerr)
```

Comment: You will need to iterate the result, or use `ToList()`/`ToArray()` after your grouping

Comment: Hi Colin

I tried it but I got the same result no change

  var test = this.Technicians.GroupBy(ter => ter.TechnicianTerr).Select(grp=>grp.ToList()).ToList() ;

            var text2 =this.Technicians.GroupBy(t => t.TechnicianTerr).Select(grp1 => new { grp1.Key, TechnicianListOfTerritories = grp1.ToList() }).ToList();

Comment: Is your collection empty?

Comment: vartest=this.Technicians.GroupBy(ter=>ter.TechnicianTerr).Select(grp=>grp.ToList()).ToList() ;

Comment: @ColinM  I have 15 records in it